Movie about a group of soldiers transporting an elephant
I saw this movie about 10-15 years ago. A group of soldiers have to transport an elephant across jungles etc to a town. They have a kid helping them, and they are constantly hounded by an enemy group of soldiers. 
At one point, the little boy is captured, but they break him out by ramming the elephant through the hut. 
Another scene is they try transporting the elephant by cargo plane and give it a sleeping pill. However, it wakes up halfway through the flight and the leftover sleeping pills were all smashed. The plane is forced to make an emergency landing when the elephant starts moving around the plane 
They finally are able to fly the elephant by building a small wooden pen for the elephant on the plane and then attaching a parachute to it. 
When they land, they meet the enemy soldiers and are captured. However, one of the good soldiers had by mistake parachuted into a tree, and now cuts himself loose. He shoots his gun into the air as a distraction and the rest of the good guys are able to fight back.

The movie might be Operation Dumbo Drop (1995):
Imdb page
Wikipedia synopsis:

During the Vietnam War in 1968, Captain Sam Cahill (Danny Glover) has
  been working hard to create good relations between the United States
  and Montagnard Vietnamese in the village of Dak Nhe. The U.S. Army is
  looking to monitor enemy operations on a clandestine weapons supply
  route which passes near the village. Cahill is coming close to his
  discharge, and explains to his successor Captain T.C. Doyle (Ray
  Liotta) the delicate nature of Vietnamese customs as well as the
  counter intelligence involving covert enemy activity. In a lapse of
  judgment with surrounding village children, a child steals a Nestlé
  Crunch bar; the wrapper, when found, lets the NVA know of the local
  villagers' cooperation with the Americans. As punishment, Brigadier
  Nguyen (Hoang Ly) of the NVA, orders his subordinate, Captain Quang
  (Vo Trung Anh), to kill the villagers' elephant right before a
  spiritual festival. To aid the villagers, Cahill promises to replace
  the slain elephant before their upcoming ceremony.

